# Feature extraction or importance for correlated time series lags

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, random-forest, feature-selection, importance

I am building a model that predicts a target variable using daily weather data. I am trying to understand which weather lags influence my target variable the most. The issue is some weather lags are highly correlated - for example, if I use monthly weather aggregates, January and October for some bizarre reason have highly correlated values for one of my variables. I have similar results with weekly weather variables (although these tend to be correlated with the previous 2 lags). If I were just interested in prediction, I'd just use PCA.

Most of the feature importance methods and metrics I am aware of, such as permutation importance, feature importance in random forests and SHAP are affected by correlated variables. What would be the best way to evaluate the feature importance in my case? Is there a way to preprocess my data to make it more favorable to my goal?

Thanks!